# Crear una carpeta "general" node_modules para React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

tengo muchos "mini" proyectos que estoy realizando en un curso de React Native. Me gustaría  que todos los proyectos en el package.json indicar la ruta de la carpeta donde estén TODOS, o lo que es lo mismo: una carpeta "general" para node_modules.

Uno de los problemas que se me presenta es con EXPO y su package.json que tendría que cambiar "_where" cada vez, ¿cierto?

¿Es posible?

De no ser posible... ¿Se podría reducir considerablemente el tamaño de la carpeta node_modules?

Gracias.

Comment: entiendo el problema, pero piensa también que cuando compiles el proyecto debes aportar la lista exacta de paquetes necesarios. Si tiras del mismo directorio de módulos, te será difícil ver cuáles debes importar y cuáles no.

Comment: Y, ¿sería posible reducir el tamaño? ¿Hay alguna forma por CLI de borrar los paquetes de node_modules no usados? Gracias.

Comment: Siempre puedes instalar todas tus dependencias de forma global, con el parámetro `--global` o su alias `-g`. Sin embargo, personalmente no lo recomiendo. También puedes reducir el tamaño de tu carpeta `node_modules` eliminando dependencias duplicadas con `npm dedup` y/o eliminando las no usadas con [`npm prune`](http://doc.codingdict.com/npm-ref/cli/prune.html). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras este comentario tuyo tiene muchísimo de respuesta ;-)